# Y from X dependency in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, differential-equations

I have solved a system of differential equations and got the answer:

x(t) = -C1*exp(-t) + C2*exp(3*t)/3

y(t) = C1*exp(-t) + C2*exp(3*t)

`X` and `y` depend on `t`. How can I plot the `y(x)` graph?

Comment: Normally you would use initial conditions for x(0) and y(0) to solve for C1 and C2. Then you can plug in a range of t values and plot that. Do you have initial conditions?

Comment: If your problem is how to plot a 2D parametric curve  in Matlab, consider the following example, which plots a semicircle: `t = linspace(0,0.5,500); x = cos(2*pi*t); y = sin(2*pi*t); plot(x, y), axis equal`